# do it changes and save Jquery PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm trying to modify a page title for example by jquery, but I can not see where I have to go to do that and to then save your changes by that title remains unchanged.

That's the code :

```
<html>
   <head>
    <title>index</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estiloP.css">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <form id="formulario" action="" method="POST"> 
        <textarea id="input" rows="4" cols="50" name="input" value='input'>
        </textarea>
        <div id="enviar" class="posicion" >
            <input type="button" value="Enviar" name="enviar" > 
        </div> 
        <div id='cambiar'> 
            <input type="button" value="cambiar" name="cambiar"  > 
        </div>
    </form>

  <iframe id="probando" src="pruebaP.html" scrolling="auto" height="350" width="750" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" name="iframe"> 
 </iframe>
    <div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var contenido = document.getElementById("probando");
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#cambiar").on('click', function () {
            var nuevoTexto = $("#input").val();
            if(nuevoTexto === "")
                alert('No ha introducido nada nuevo');
            else{
               alert(nuevoTexto);                  
            }                
            });
        });
    </script>

</body>
```

Comment: explain in detail..what you exactly want to do?

Comment: I really don't get it..  if you want to edit the title of the page.. you can change the element content of the element `<title></title>`.. it's below the head element.

Comment: I want to make a small application that allows me to change the title , paragraphs and photos of the product . And do not know how to edit a text and then it is saved

Answer (score 2):

for change page title use:-

```
$(document).prop('title', 'your title');
```

Or

```
document.title = 'your title';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to only change it once it's pretty easy, look at your code :

```
<html>
   <head>
    <title>index</title>
```

There is the title tag, see?

Just change its content to whatever you want, safe, refresh the web page, and it should work :

```
<html>
   <head>
    <title>My Sweet Title</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estiloP.css">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <form id="formulario" action="" method="POST"> 
        <textarea id="input" rows="4" cols="50" name="input" value='input'
                  ></textarea>
        <div id="enviar" class="posicion" >
            <input type="button" value="Enviar" name="enviar" > 
        </div> 
        <div id='cambiar'> 
            <input type="button" value="cambiar" name="cambiar"  > 
        </div>
    </form>
    <iframe id="probando" src="pruebaP.html" scrolling="auto" height="350" width="750" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" name="iframe"></iframe>
    <div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var contenido = document.getElementById("probando");
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#cambiar").on('click', function () {
            var nuevoTexto = $("#input").val();
            if(nuevoTexto === "")
                alert('No ha introducido nada nuevo');
            else{
               alert(nuevoTexto);                  
            }                
            });
        });
    </script>

</body>
```

Comment: Thanks but it's not exactly what I need .
I want to make a small application that allows me to change the title , paragraphs and photos of the product . And do not know how to edit a text and then it is saved .
But thank you very much .

Comment: What you are looking for is called CMS. Maybe take a look at Wordpress.